# List Box Multiple Selected values

Tags: listbox, state-management

how to pass multiple selected list box values which are in a session in one ascx page to another ascx page
Code is
NameObjectCollection eeSearchString=new NameObjectCollection();

```
                for(i = 0;i <= LbStatus.Items.Count - 1){
                if LbStatus.Items(i).Selected {                   
                eeSearchString.Add(new NameObjectPair("status", LbStatus.SelectedItem(i).Text));
                    }
                }
```

And in another page can i access the status like this?

```
  _status=Convert.ToString(eeSearchString.ItemValue("status"));
```

Pls let me know?? or do i need to use loop again???

Comment: Do you have any code you're written so far?

Comment: i hope you accept ans if its works for you

Answer (score 0):

make use of session variable or make use of properties of the control, i.e create property and assign value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about aspx but in HTMl you can declare an array for some elements.

For example:

Group XPTO

In the server, in my case, in PHP I only receive the Value of the ones that are selected inside the array.

Image you have this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="1" /> Group 1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="2" /> Group 2 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="3" /> Group 3 <br />
```

Imagine you've selected the Group 1 and 3. In the server you'll receive the array with the values of the group1 and 3.

```
group(1, 3);
```

Hope this helps with you're question =)

Regards,

Elkas